# Store list of object in SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework to connect my SQL Server database in my C# app.

I have a `Location` class, which looks like this :

```
[Table("DBLocation")]
public class DBLocation {
    // ...
    public List<DBPicture> pictures{ get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

My problem is, how am I supposed to store the list into the database, do I create another table to match Location IDs and pictures, if yes how do I tell the code to use that ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a model and assign the object's variable to the model's fields

Comment: You mean, something like a LocationPicture class, with tho integers fields like idLocation and idPicture ?

Comment: yes! same thing :)

Comment: Right, that's what i had in mind. But with that second class, how will the data "fill" the DBLocation class ? Do i need like a constructor telling DBLocation to fill the list using the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be something like this,

```
 public void savePicture(List<DBPicture> pics)
        {
            //Getting a list of pics of type DBPicture as you mentioned in class
            try
            {
                foreach(DBPicture pic in pics)
                //Using the model created from database 
                using (DataModel.PicEntities picContext = new PicEntities())
                {

                    DataModel.DBPicture dbPic = new DBPicture();
                    dbPic.idPic = pic.idPicture;
                    dbPic.idLoc = pic.idLocation;
                    picContext.Meetings.Add(dbPic);
                    picContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
```